# Automatically annotating training phrases while batch updating them using Dialogflow REST API V2

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm using the dialogflow REST API V2 to [batchUpdate](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/batchUpdate) intents, ie, post more training phrases to each intent in my dialogflow agent using Node.js. I have these training phrases in a .txt file(phrases separated by a '\n' character) which my node.js script parses into a [training phrase](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#TrainingPhrase) object before calling the batchUpdate method. My current agent has a bunch of custom entities that I have created. I use the [entity List](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/list) method to grab hold of all the entities I've defined and manually get the code to check for the presence of any of these entity types in my training phrases to parse it accordingly.

My problem is, however, that I'd like dialogflow to automatically detect some of the system defined entities during the process (eg. @sys.given-name, @sys.date, etc.). I don't seem to have any problem in capturing the custom entities as my script "sniffs" out these entity types and breaks my training phrase down into the corresponding [parts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#Part). I'd like for dialogflow to similarly annotate the **system defined** entities without me having to manually break the training phrase down into parts again.

I see that the [part](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#Part) object has a parameter called "userDefined" parameter that I don't completely understand. Toggling with this parameter hasn't changed anything in my training phrase object. I can also see that the [TrainingPhrase](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#TrainingPhrase) object comes with a "type" parameter that I've tried experimenting with as well. I don't clearly understand what TYPE_UNSPECIFIED means and why EXAMPLE is the the only other option there is, which doesn't allow for @-prefixed entity type names to be contained in the training phrase.

Is there a parameter that I'm possibly not setting in my training phrase object to allow for dialogflow to automatically detect these @-prefixed entity type names?

Here's the intentBatch object I'm using in my request body.

```
{
  "intentBatchInline": {
    "intents": [
      {
        "displayName": "cheese",
        "name": " projects/copy-c6f8c/agent/intents/07207104-75f1-4ed0-b97a-8d6931f9049e",
        "trainingPhrases": [
          {
            "type": "TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
            "parts": [
              {
                "text": "Here's my Indian phone number: 5432543243",
                "userDefined": false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I found in their documentation that the API cannot automatically annotate the phrases like the Dialogflow console does. If anyone has any other suggestions or NLP Libraries that can help me annotate my phrases with some pre-defined entities, please let me know.

[image: [Link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#TrainingPhrase)]